# MVC 5: Controller, Database and View have strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity

So I have this little "Restaurant" webapp going on where I'm trying to construct a View-page where an user can click on a created (restaurant) table (dropdown that refreshes automatically after clicking) and check what dishes are ordered on that table. At the bottom, the user will find the total price.

My view works 100% fine but ONLY if I have 1 table in the database. If I have multiple tables (restaurant tables) (created in my DropCreate-Seed method), the view will only show the dropdown with available tables, not the dishes inside of them.

What could cause this problem?

**CODE**

**TABLE**

```
 public class Table
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    }
```

**SEED METHOD**

```
context.Tables.Add(new Table {  Id = 1 ,Name = "table1", Dishes = context.Dishes.ToList() });
            context.Tables.Add(new Table { Id = 2, Name = "table2", Dishes = context.Dishes.ToList() });
            context.Tables.Add(new Table { Id = 3, Name = "table3", Dishes = context.Dishes.ToList() });
            context.SaveChanges();
```

**TABLE CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Order(int? tableID)
        {
            //Create a ViewBag variable contained with all the tables (show name)
            List<table> tableL = db.tables.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> tableSL = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var table in tableL)
            {
                TableSL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = table.Name.ToLower(), Value = table.Name.ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.tableL = tableSL;

            //At the start or at problems, get the first table and return it
            if (tableID == null || db.tables.Find(tableID) == null)
            {
                return View(db.tables.First());
            }
            else
            {
                Table l = db.tables.Find(tableID);
                return View(l);
            }     
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model VBExamenTEST.Models.Table
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Order";
}

<h2>Order</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Bedien", "Bedien", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("tableID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TableL, new {onchange = "this.form.submit()" });
}

@if(Model != null)
{
    double total = 0;
    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach(var g in Model.Dishes)
            {
                total += g.Price;
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model=>g.Name)
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Total:@total euro </p>
}
```

---

So my code works perfectly if I only have one table added in my DB, whenever I add more, only the dropdown shows up, the dishes are not shown on click, and the total equals 0.

Where can my problem be situated?

Comment: You creating a `SelectListItems` with the value attribute equal to the table `Name` so you post back `"table2"` or `"table3"` and `db.tables.Find("table3");` would not return `null` - the `Value` property needs to be the `ID` of `Table`. In any case, you should consider using ajax for this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
Thank you very much for your comment! What a stupid mistake of me, but after changing the value property to '.ID', it told me it needs to be a string. after doing 'Value = table.ID.ToString()' however, it also doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure that there are better alternatives, but sadly, my teacher doesn't allow us to use those :(. Thank you very much again for your comment

Comment: Your `@using (Html.BeginForm("Bedien", "Bedien", FormMethod.Post))` also does not look right - I assume you mean `"Order"`? And it needs to be `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, Indeed, I translated my code to English but forgot to translate that function header. I also edited the .Post to .Get and now only the 3rd table seems to be working. I'm thinking this has something to do with my database.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your trying to do with this - all you will ever do is return exactly the same collection of `Dish` (not what is related to a tables order. Do you have a `TableDish` table that stores the ID of the `Table` and the ID of the `Dish` (i.e. for the many-many relationship)?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know to add a list of Tables in the Dish class! My code is working flawlessly now! Thank you very much for you help Stephen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113197/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kahn-kah).